# Setting Dataframe loc result in SQL string - Tuples Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pyodbc

I'm getting a tuples error when I use df.loc value in a pd.read_sql_query string.

```
import pyodbc as db
import pandas as pd

#Connection String
Conn = db.connect('Driver={driver};Server=server;Database=db;Trusted_Connection=yes')

#DataFrame that stores SQL LookUp Table
dfSQLLookUp = pd.read_sql_query('Select col1, 
col2 from dbo.LookUp_TableNames', Conn)

#Loop to store table in Dataframe and (eventually) ouput to Excel file
varIndex = -1
for i in dfSQLLookUp.itertuples():
varIndex += 1
dfResults = pd.read_sql_query('if (exists (select * from information_schema.TABLES where TABLE_SCHEMA = dbo and TABLE_NAME = {})) select * from dbo.{} else print table does not exist'.format(dfSQLLookUp.loc[varIndex, 'SQLTableNameColumn']), Conn)
```

When I print the df.loc value:

```
import pyodbc as db
import pandas as pd

#Connection String
Conn = db.connect('Driver={driver};Server=server;Database=db;Trusted_Connection=yes')

#DataFrame that stores SQL LookUp Table
dfSQLLookUp = pd.read_sql_query('Select col1, 
col2 from dbo.LookUp_TableNames', Conn)

varIndex = -1
for i in dfSQLNames.itertuples():
    varIndex += 1
    print (dfSQLNames.loc[varIndex, 'IFSFlatFileName'])
```

The correct string values are returned. Is this a problem with the pd.read_sql_query syntax? Or is the tuples error something else? Any insight is appreciated.

Tuples Error text:

> dfResults = pd.read_sql_query('if (exists (select * from
>   information_schema.TABLES where TABLE_SCHEMA = dbo and TABLE_NAME =
>   {})) select * from dbo.{} else print table does not
>   exist'.format(dfSQLLookUp.loc[varIndex, 'SQLTableNamesColumn']), Conn)
>   IndexError: tuple index out of range Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? AFAIK you can use only plain SQL (not T-SQL) in Pandas / SQL Alchemy...

Comment: I'm pulling all data from any SQL table whose name is found in the dfSQLLookUp dataframe and writing the results to individual csv files. The "if (exists" statement is because some of the table names in dfSQLLookUp do not exist as SQL tables. These will be handled later on in an if statement. 

Can I use a stored procedure in SQL Alchemy? What is the preferred alternative to SQL Alchemy if I need to seek alternatives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @MaxU mentioned in the comments, Pandas / SQL Alchemy doesn't support T-SQL. This is most likely what was throwing the tuples error. To get around the limitations of Pandas / SQL Alchemy, I created a stored procedure in SQL to populate the look up table. I also had to SET NOCOUNT ON in the procedure as I was getting a NullType error when calling the procedure in Python. Below is the final result. Hopefully this helps others in my place.

```
import pyodbc as db
import pandas as pd

#Database Connection String
Conn = db.connect('Driver={driver};Server=server;Database=db;Trusted_Connection=yes')

#DataFrame that stores the LookUp values for the SQL table names and the Excel file names
dfSQLLookUp = pd.read_sql_query('Exec dbo.uspDataFrameLookUp', Conn)

#Loop to store SQL tables in a Dataframe and output to Excel file
varIndex = -1
for i in dfSQLLookUp.itertuples():
    varIndex += 1
    dfResults = pd.read_sql_query('select * from dbo.{}'.format(dfSQLLookUp.loc[varIndex, 'NameOfCol1']), Conn)

    #Writing the Dataframe to an Excel file
    OutputDirectory = r'\\path\...\PythonExtracts\{}.xlsx'.format(dfSQLLookUp.loc[varIndex, 'NameOfCol2'])
    Excel = pd.ExcelWriter(OutputDirectory, engine='xlsxwriter')
    dfResults.to_excel(Excel, sheet_name='Sheet1')
    Excel.save()

Conn.close()
```

Stored Procedure

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[uspDataFrameLookUp]
as

begin

set nocount on

declare @varTableName nvarchar(30)
declare @varCountRows int
declare @varCountLoop int
declare @varDFTable table (NameOfCol1 nvarchar(50), 
NameOfCol2 nvarchar(50))

set @varCountRows = (select count(*) from [dbo].[LookUp_TableNames])
set @varCountLoop = 0

while @varCountLoop <= @varCountRows
begin
set @varCountLoop = @varCountLoop + 1
set @varTableName = (select NameOfCol1 from 
dbo.LookUp_TableNames where ID = @varCountLoop)
if (exists (select * 
                from information_schema.TABLES 
                where TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo' 
                and TABLE_NAME = @varTableName))

    insert into @varDFTable 
            select NameOfCol1, NameOfCol2
            from dbo.LookUp_TableNames 
            where NameOfCol1 = @varTableName
end

select * from @varDFTable order by NameOfCol1 asc

end
```